# How to tell chrome language of your web site (as a hint to the translate bar)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, translation

I have a web app that is in queens engrish but the chrome translate bar pops up and tells me that its in Estonian.

I have tried lang and xml:lang but the google translation bar seems to ignore these.

Note: The web application is totally Ajax and the content that causes the bar to pop up is dynamic content that can appear long after the page load.  So perhaps I have to add a header to my Ajax responses??

Anyone ever had issues like this?

Guido

Comment: I'm also having this exact problem, except the language is "Galician."  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I would just add a lot of text in the about section or in a hidden div,  or something like that - your browser may need some more text to correctly define a language.
You're not the first one to have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980520/how-to-specify-your-webpages-language-so-google-chrome-doesnt-offer-to-transla).

They said you could avoid translation by doing this:

```
<body class="notranslate">
```

or:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

But have a look yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but you could add Estonian as one of your preferred languages, then Chrome wouldn't offer to translate it for you.

This [google language detection code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect) might help you identify where the problem is.

Comment: I know how to disable the chrome bar in my browser.  I want to make sure it does not pop up on other peoples browsers when using this app.