# Google Chrome - Offering translation when none is needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

So I have written a page, but keep getting prompted to translate the page into English (From Indonesian).  It's already in English so I don't know what's going on.  I have searched around and tried a bunch of fixes, but none of them seem to work.

I included this stuff in my head:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000" />  
    .
    .
    .
```

In an effort to counteract the translation stuff.  Unfortunately, this does not work.    Is anyone aware of what might be causing this behavior?  I really wish we could just hide the translation bar using CSS, but alas, Google got wise and changed the structure so it's not a div in the page...  Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `<html lang="en">`? This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980520/how-to-specify-your-webpages-language-so-google-chrome-doesnt-offer-to-transla.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome seems to ignore that as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "content", not "value":

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

Comment: [The docs](http://support.google.com/translate/#2641276) state otherwise, though.

Comment: Alas, neither of those worked.  It's strange, I can add that, and it does not display when the page first loads; however, after navigating away from the page, it pops down.  Very strange.

Comment: Yes, so it hides it when on the initial load.  When you navigate away to ANY other page, it will slide down.

Comment: @gabaum10 what do you mwan by "ANY other page"?  Another page in your domain, or any other page on the Internet?  The `<meta>` tag isn't intended to declare the "notranslate" for your entire site - it's a per-page flag.

Comment: Well, my page is constructed through a JSP/JSPF structure, so the meta tag is in a header.jspf file (included in every page).  And it's any other page on my domain.  It does not do that whilst hitting an external domain (tried google.com)

Comment: @pimvdb yes, but the HTML5 spec says that there's no "value" attribute for `<meta>` tags.

Comment: So, after clearing the cache, rebuilding my project and rerunning the app, some combination of the things mentioned solved the problem.  I am really not sure which one it was.  I am going to try to isolate exactly which solution was the right answer.

Comment: I believe changing it to "content" did the trick.  I removed the other crap I tried and it still solved the problem.  Apparently there was some caching that needed to be cleared for it to take effect.  Thanks for the help boys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server response, you can send a `Content-Language` response header that Chrome will honor.  For example:

I think you said you were using JSP:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Language, "en");
```

Here it is for ASP.Net:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Language", "en");
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

i added a content-length header and it stopped

working in node.js

```
          // ...

          var html    = '<div>helloworld</div>';

          res.writeHead(200,{
                'content-type'      : 'text/html',
                'content-length'    : html.length
          });

          res.end(html);

          // ...
```