# chrome shows "page is in malay" but my web page has been written in english

Tags: html, google-chrome, toolbar, language-translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Chrome incorrectly determine page is in a different language and offer to translate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer)

My entire page is written in English and not in Malay. However, chrome shows that the page is in Malay. What changes should I do in my code? Is it some HTML standard that I didn't adhere to?

Comment: i have lorem ipsum on my site so chrome thinks its french.  Anyway, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980520/how-to-specify-your-webpages-language-so-google-chrome-doesnt-offer-to-transla

Comment: check this thread :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer

Comment: even if i use <meta name="google" value="notranslate" /> , this may not be best solution because even if people from other countries want to translate , they can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what editor you used to save the file. Assuming you used Dreamweaver, there is a thing called BOM (byte order mark), when you look at the page properties in Dreamweaver, there should be encoding setting and the check box for BOM. It's possible that either the page was saved with Malay encoding. BOM signals that the text stream (file) is Unicode when set.

Comment: i am using a text editor called "Geany" and i looked at the page property , it says "Encoding: UTF-8 (without BOM)"

Comment: I just googled for Geany BOM problems and it seems that there is a bug which might be what you are seeing. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2155580&group_id=153444&atid=787791

Comment: Thanks for the effort!! no, i cant save with BOM..there is no such options while saving and i guess the issue hasn't been fixed yet :(

Comment: It shouldn't matter much. UTF-8 is not language specific and browsers will assume UTF-8 when in doubt these days. Another related source apart from the BOM you could check is the Content-Type header/meta tag. But I see no indication that Google Translate actually looks at these things. In fact they explicitly say they don't look at code-level indicators and instead only look at the text content of the page.