# This page is in Hungarian

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a simple website in VS 2010 that uses master pages. All pages are ok except the most simple of contact pages. I've pasted the markup below. There is nothing in the code-behind. Problem is, when I browse to the page, Chrome displays a message telling me that "This page is in Hungarian". I've even tried deleting the page and re-creating with a different name but get the same problem. Can anyone tell me why?

```
<div id="info">
    <p class="red">
        <span class="main"><strong>Email:</strong></span> <span class="redlink"><a href="mailto:info@zzz.co.uk">
            info@zzz.co.uk</a></span><br />
        <!--span class="main"><strong>Telephone: </strong></span>0843 2895339</p>!-->
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer-t

Comment: Could it be a declaration in your header?

Comment: Yep, "z" is pretty common in Hungarian. Need to go catch the busz now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the web.config. Probably set to a different culture.

You probably need to change it to something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <globalization culture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or if it's only on that page, check the culture and UI culture in the page directive and adjust it accordingly.