# How to remove translation warning by Google chrome browser? Chrome saying page is in Malay when its in English

Tags: html, google-chrome, translation

My HTML page is in English language, I dont see any text in Malay language, but still when I check it in chrome browser, it says "this page is in malay language wuld you like to translate it?" ....whats the solution to remove it.

snapshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55938469/1.JPG

Can anybody tell me how do I tell the browser that this page is English and dont show this warning to anybody viewing this page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome incorrectly determine page is in a different language and offer to translate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

But it will disable translate for people who want to translate page to their native non-english languages

Answer (score 3):

Change language in your HTML tag

```
<HTML lang="en">
```

or this

```
<BODY LANG=en>
```