# Chrome language error

Tags: google-chrome, joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Chrome incorrectly determine page is in a different language and offer to translate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454/why-does-chrome-incorrectly-determine-page-is-in-a-different-language-and-offer)

On one of my pages chrome tells that my page is written in Portuguese. It is in Spanish. I can't figure out why this is happening. Here is the link: [Web page](http://applesat.com/index.php/tarifas)

All other pages are ok, without any errors.

I use Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Google's language algorithms aren't the best.

Try being explicit with your meta tag for content-language

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es-es">
```